# Mail is not sending in Google Cloud in Vesta panel Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, google-cloud

I configured Vesta Panel in Debian 9 for my magento 2 website. But mail is not working, there is no errors. But I am not receiving any mails to my mail from google cloud. I wrote firewall rules. If anybody know anything to resolve this issue, please respond me.

Comment: Please check your cron job is set or not?. If not set then first set your cron job and check.

Comment: Make sure that simple PHP mails are working, try to test with phptestmail

Comment: I have setted up cron job already. But I can't receive any emails from server

Comment: there is no mail servers in my server. I have configured only with IP. I didn't purchase a domain name. No I didn't get email from phptestmail

Comment: @tamilSelvan its ok if you dont pointed any domain yet, are you using any SMTP module to send emails ?